# python tkinter mouse position "bind('<Motion>')" return wrong position

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem is when the cursor is over one of these widgets `Listbox` , `Label`, `Text` the position becomes wrong

[Right position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwiuc.png)

[Wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGwGm.png)

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')
position = Label(root)
position.place(relx = 0.25, rely = 0.25)
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.place(relx = .5, rely = .5, relwidth = .5, relheight = .5)
root.bind('<Motion>', lambda e : position.config(text = f'({e.x},{e.y})'))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: its changing the position once u change the widget, the `bind` is for the root right? if you change to `listbox.bind(...)` you would get a different result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is relative to the widget, not the window. When your mouse moves over the listbox, the event goes to the listbox rather than the root window.

If you want the coordinates relative to the window, use `e.x_root` and `e.y_root`